# javascript Filter array with duplicate elements at a specific occurrence

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, object

I have an array of names which all have duplicates.

```
let arr = ['John', 'Jack', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'June', 'June'];
```

I want to create a new array with some of the duplicate elements, specifying an instance at which they occur.

For example, I may want the array to contain only the second occurrence of John, Jack and June. The array will look like this:

```
'John', 'Jack', 'June'
```

To accomplish this, I have declared an object `ni` and looped through `arr` to add properties to the object corresponding to each name; the property will hold the value of an array containing each index at which the name occurs.

```
let ni  = {};

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let name = arr[i];
  if(nc.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    ni[name].push(i);
  } else {
    ni[name] = [i];
  }
}

console.log(ni);
// > Object { John: Array [0, 2], Jack: Array [1, 3, 4], June: Array [5, 6] }
```

In my Array.filter function, I check if the element's index is equal to index 1 of the object property corresponding to the same name.

```
let newArr = arr.filter(function(name) {
  if(ni.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    return arr.indexOf(name) === ni[name][1];
  }
});
```

This should return `John` at `index 2`, `Jack` at `index 3`, and `June` at `index 6` to the new array.

However, this has not worked. Logging `newArr` to the console will output an array completely unchanged from the original.

```
> Array ["John", "Jack", "John", "Jack", "Jack", "June", "June"]
```

Comment: So, basically return names with more than one occurrence?

Comment: Contrary to what you claim, `newArr` as returned by the filter, is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

You can use some simple array logic like so:

```
let newArr = arr.filter((e, i) => i == ni[e][1]);
```

Comment: @trincot In case the array does not contain enough elements - so if it's undefined, it will take the last element of the array instead.

Comment: But that will always be truthy (note that `==` has precedence over `||`) for non-empty strings. Secondly, it defeats the purpose, because `length` could be 1 and then you  get the first occurrence. OP wants the second...

Comment: So I should remove the `||` part?

Comment: Yes, I was going to answer at the same time you did, but only with that difference, so better you have it without it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback @trincot I'm still refining my knowledge on precedence, I'll keep what you mentioned in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to count the occurrence of each name. If the name's count is 2, then push to another array. This way you don't have to run nested array methods:

```js
const array = ['Jane', 'John', 'Jack', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'June', 'June'];
const filtered = [];
const count = array.reduce((a, name) => {
  a[name] = a[name] + 1 || 1;
  if(a[name] === 2)
    filtered.push(name)
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(filtered)
```

Or get the keys of the counter with count > 1

```js
const array = ['Jane', 'John', 'Jack', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'June', 'June'],
      count = array.reduce((a, n) => (a[n] = a[n] + 1 || 1, a), {}),
      filtered = Object.keys(count).filter(n => count[n] > 1);
      
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm creating an object instead of an array because it seems more suitable to map from name to the index of the 2nd appearance. It works like this: `indexOf` returns the index of the 1st occurrence of an element in the array so if `indexOf` is not equal to the current index then it's 2nd or later occurrence, then I check whether the name is not already in the return object so I know it's not 3rd or later occurrence.

```js
let arr = ['John', 'Jack', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'June', 'June'];
let newObj = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur, idx) {
  if (arr.indexOf(cur)!==idx && !acc[cur]) { acc[cur] = idx; }
 return acc;
}, {});
console.log(newObj);
```